# Are there any proofs that use $0/0$ is indeterminate?

Tags: proof-writing

I'd imagine that "$n/0$ is undefined $\forall n\neq 0$" is very useful in finding contradictions, but are there any proofs that somehow use "$0/0$ is indeterminate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use that $0/0$ is indeterminate to conclude that certain expressions are in fact $0$ (and this is pretty much the only thing you can use $0/0$ for). However, nobody writes down such arguments because:

1. Writing such an argument requires you to be very careful, hence requires a lot of effort.
2. Any such argument can be replaced by a much easier argument of the form "Either the expression is $0$, or I get a contradiction: therefore the expression is $0$".

For an example of how to use that $\dfrac 00$ is indeterminate (and for a more general explanation of what it means to "divide by $0$", see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/633298/400)). On the flip-side, the fact that no number corresponds to the faction $\dfrac n0$ for $n\neq0$ is incredibly useful: for example, if you have an expression $\lim\dfrac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ and you (carefully) reduce it to an expression of the form $\dfrac n0$ where $n\neq0$, you can conclude that the limit does not exist, without mucking about with $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s.

Answer (score -1):

Hope I understood you correctly, but here's a very simple example.

consider $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x}$. it tends to one.

Now consider $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x}{x}$. it tends to two.

We have 2 different limits to something that is close to $\frac{0}{0}$.

Was this helpful?

Comment: In both cases you can just divide out the x to get a constant equation, so I don't think these examples really apply.

Comment: @Hovercouch
You can multiply the equation $\frac{0}{0}$ with any number since $0*k=0$,so yeah it pretty much explains stuff