# Has there ever been an application of dividing by $0$?

Tags: divisibility, axioms

Regarding the expression $a/0$, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero):

> In ordinary arithmetic, the expression has no meaning, as there is no number which, multiplied by $0$, gives $a$ (assuming $a\not= 0$), and so division by zero is undefined.

Is there some *other* kind of mathematics that is not "ordinary", where the expression $a/0$ has meaning? Or is the word "ordinary" being used superfluously in the quoted statement?

Is there any abstract application of $a/0$?

Comment: Sure. Look up projective geometry. $\frac{1}{0}$, or just $\infty$, is a convenient name for the "point at infinity" on the projective line.

Comment: Something that may be of interest: $$\lim_{x,y \to 0} x^y$$

Comment: I don't know if the first comment covers this, since I'm not good at projective geometry, but if we compactify the real line using one point (i.e. "turn it into an infinite circle" - see Alexandroff compactification), then we can make the function $1\over x^p$ continuous on the ENTIRE real line, not just at $x \not= 0$ by defining $1/x=\infty$ in accordance with "intuition".

Comment: This is of course the most shocking heresy but [if $a=0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595531/can-0-0-be-allowed-if-it-can-be-defined).

Comment: @selfawareuser if a = 0 then we have 0/0 which also has no meaning as demonstrated in a different set of proofs not included in the quoted statement. https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/dividing-by-zero.html

Comment: In the view of the stereographic projection, $\infty$ is just as normal a point as are any other points on the Riemannian sphere.

Comment: @LorryLaurencemcLarry If you asked Euler, he would have said that $0/0$ can be anything; see Chapter 3 paragraphs 84 and 85 of http://imcs.dvfu.ru/lib.int/NEW/Math/MC_Calculus/MCet_Elementary%20calculus%20textbooks/Euler%20L.%20Foundations%20of%20Differential%20Calculus%20(Springer,2000)(ISBN%200387985344)(211s).pdf

Comment: @LorryLaurencemcLarry: Your link is ok, but it _is_ rather elementary. It doesn't actually say that $0/0$ is undefined, it says that it's [_indeterminate_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#Indeterminate_form_0.2F0). As my Wikipedia link shows, if we know where those zeroes come from we _can_ often assign a definite value to $0/0$. To be more precise, given two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ with $f(0)=g(0)$ then it's often possible to find a unique value for $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$.

Comment: physicians divide by 0 on a daily basis - as you may expect, $x/0=∞$, and it follows as completely valid, because $∞=$`"too large to be measured or accounted for"`, $0 = $`"too small to be measured or accounted for"` - thus a division by $0$ (note: usually not being the "real" mathematical zero) is commonly used,

Comment: @zerosofthezeta The most interesting fact about that expression is that it is ill-defined. First you have to define what $x,y\rightarrow 0$ even means. And for any sensible definition of that, your expression would be undefined.

Comment: In poker you calculate pot odds  as pot / bet.  If you just check (bet 0) and the pot is > 0  you are getting infinite pot odds.  I get it is non deterministic as infinity * 0 != pot but some times you don't need deterministic.

Comment: This is nothing serious like the answers above but there is this attempt of dividing by zero in this old calculator and it goes in a endless loop. Check the video here [Facit ESA-01 division by zero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BT7dxgs0gjo) I saw this a couple of days ago and thought this might of interest to someone here.

Comment: There is no problem in defining the result of $a/0$ to be $\infty$. The problem is that $\infty$ won't have properties we expect from a number.

Answer (score 68):

You said you wanted an application.  Inspired by the example from [Exceptional Floating Point](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/04/21/exceptional-floating-point/), consider the [parallel resistance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits#Resistors_2):$$
    R_{total} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}}
$$This formula tells you the effective electrical resistance of a path when the current can choose two routes to take.

Let's pretend that $R_1=0$.  Then we have:$$
    R_{total}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{0}+\frac{1}{R_2}}=\frac{1}{\infty+\frac{1}{R_2}}=\frac{1}{\infty}=0
$$The resistance being zero is indeed the correct answer; all current flows along the single wire that has no resistance.

Naturally, you need to make appropriate definitions for arithmetic on $\infty$ (i.e., use the projective reals).  For well-behaved applications like this, that's fairly straightforward.

Comment: I don't think $0$ resistance is technically possible---should the wire itself not have some, albeit negligible, resistance? This is a somewhat idealized situation.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 [Superconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity) have *exactly* zero electrical resistance and have [many practical applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_applications_of_superconductivity).

Comment: @Insilico Interesting, I guess I was wrong. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Pretty much all electrical CAD software models wires as connections with exactly 0 resistance.

Comment: @Insilico Type II superconductors often have miniscule and imperceptible, but non-zero resistances under certain conditions that are often seen in practical use.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Wire has a resistance of 0 in the same way that a spherical cow falls in a vacuum. It's an abstraction used by practitioners in the field because it's Close Enough.

Comment: @Insilico, I find it hard to believe that anything has *exactly* zero resistance. Presumably, what's really going on is that our understanding of superconductivity is based on a model, an idealization, and in that model, the resistance is exactly $0$. But I bet you one day we'll have a better model, and the predicted resistance will be small-but-nonzero in that better model.

Comment: @goblin Our understanding of superconductivity is based on measurement, not models; when it was discovered, we had no clue how to explain it. Zero resistance was based on multiyear experiments. Maybe you're right, and it's not zero, but "I find it hard to believe" is not an appropriate justification for ignoring a large body of experiments on the subject.

Comment: @slebetman, it's true that skepticism decreases the probability of arriving at correct and/or useful conclusions. However, it also decreases the probability of arriving at incorrect and/or harmful conclusions. If so, then anyone who wants to take issue with the phrase "I find it hard to believe" - which is, after all, tantamount to uniform opposition to skepticism - had better not mind looking... let us say - a little foolish.

Comment: @prosfilaes, well, I didn't know any of that. But in fact this just bolsters my point! Since when was the experimental paradigm *ever* capable of demonstrating that a given real-valued quantity is *precisely* zero? I don't care if you have 100,000 experiments showing that it's smaller than we can currently detect, this doesn't even *begin* to establish that it's exactly $0$. By the way, I think your attempt to make my point, which was, after all, about the nature of logic and evidence, into a form of book-burning or "antiscience" was in rather poor form.

Comment: @Luaan, well, I'm no physicist, so I'm not really qualified to answer. But a few comments: firstly, I tend to think there's a difference between "superconductors don't have resistance" and "superconductors have resistance $0$." The former seems to express that the usual model of charge flow simply doesn't apply to superconductors, while the latter suggests that the usual model of charge flow *does* apply, and that the resistance is *exactly* zero. The former may be correct; the latter certainly is not. But if so, then my point that superconductors cannot be said to have exactly zero...

Comment: ...resistance is correct. The other comment I'd make is that photons, electrons, etc. are approximately described by a wavefunction, and this wavefunction does not reside completely in the superconductor. So even if the superconductor really is as perfect as you seem to be claiming, which seems unlikely given that it's made of lots and lots of particles, some of which probably have a lot of energy, nonetheless this still wouldn't imply exactly zero resistance, even in theory, because the wavefunctions are partly outside the superconductor. It may also be the case that space is "foamy" at...

Comment: very small distances, which could potentially introduce resistance into the movement even of photons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39323/discussion-between-luaan-and-goblin).

Comment: @Luaan, maybe some other day. I'm very busy for the next week or so.

Comment: @goblin I just deleted my comments so that they don't pollute the answer :P If you want to revisit this, we can continue some other time. I just posted a bit more explanation than is useful in comment-format :D

Answer (score 34):

In complex analysis, we talk about the value of a function at infinity. To evaluate $f(z)$ at infinity, compute $f(1/z)$ then plug in $0$. This allows us to talk about things like the order of zeros and poles at infinity.

Example: $$f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$ with $ad-bc \neq 0$ and say $a,c \neq 0$. $$f(1/z) = \frac{\frac{a}{z}+b}{\frac{c}{z}+d} = \frac{a+bz}{c+dz}$$ So $f(\infty) = \frac{a}{c}$.

Comment: Couldn't you do the same thing with limits? Why do you need to define division by zero here?

Comment: @jpmc26: Why would you go through all the trouble with limits when you can just do arithmetic?

Comment: @jpmc26: It's difficult to use limits here since we are in the complex plane, and thus you would have to show that the limit of $f$ is independant of the path used to go to infinity...

Comment: @Hurkyl Doesn't all the math here still hold if you use $\lim_{z\to0} f(\frac{1}{z})$? Alex: Isn't that important even if you try to define $\frac{1}{0}$? If the function has multiple values as you approach infinity, I'm not sure how you can handwave that away by declaring $\frac{1}{0} = \infty$.

Comment: @jpmc26: Sure; in this setting, $1/x$ is continuous at $x=0$ so you can always replace it with a limit (and vice versa), but again, why go through all the trouble with limits when you can just do arithmetic?

Comment: @Hurkyl I'm asking the opposite question, though. Why *redefine* arithmetic when you can use limits? I assume that doing so leads to other complications. Also, how is $\frac{1}{x}$ continuous? It wouldn't be even if you do define $\frac{1}{0}$ since it hops between $-\infty$ and $\infty$ when you cross from $x < 0$ to $x > 0$. It doesn't seem like defining $\frac{1}{0} = \infty$ simplifies anything here. I feel like there's something major I'm missing, but I really don't know what. But that's my point: this answer doesn't point out where the knowledge gap is.

Comment: In general, it makes no sense at all to talk about "_the_ value of a complex function at infinity" because _the_ limit need not exist.

Comment: @AnotherTest: While true (but not necessarily for the reason stated), that's only in the same way it makes no sense at all to talk about "*the* value of a complex function at 1", since complex functions might be undefined at 1 as well.

Comment: @Hurkyl I completely agree that it generally makes no sense to talk about the value of a function at a value which does not belong to its domain. Following the definition of "value at" of the answer, one would have to consider a limit instead, but this is not generally possible. My comment was meant to point out that the "value at infinity" can only be reasonably defined as a limit, but this definition does not work for any function. The answer says "a function" (without specifying any other conditions) and hence is incomplete.

Comment: @AnotherTest: Limits aren't the only reasonable way. In fact, I have the impression that the relevant notion of "at infinity" here was first worked out and made rigorous through the algebraic means of using projective coordinates.

Answer (score 27):

The algebraic structure "[wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory)" is an algebra with division by zero.  The one point compactification of the complex plane into the Riemann sphere almost produces a wheel (one still needs to adjoin the element $0/0$).

Answer (score 14):

This may not be what you would consider an "application', but for computer floating point arithmetic, division by zero is useful for setting up three special values: 1.0/0.0 gives +inf, which is a valid floating point value satisfying the usual extended number line properties. -1.0/0.0 gives -inf, and my all-time favorite is 0.0/0.0, which gives NaN (not-a-number). In spite of the name, NaNs are also valid floating point numbers in the IEEE 754 standard, which almost all modern computers implement. A few languages like MATLAB let you directly specify those (e.g., a statement like *x = inf* is allowed) but others do not allow this - requiring the divide by zero syntax.

Possibly irrelevant to you but NaNs are useful in some numerical computing applications and highly useful in debugging some codes. The plural "NaNs" is valid because there are many of them: at least $2^{51}$ of them in 64-bit arithmetic. If you are interested, look for papers written by W. Kahan (father and grand inquisitor for the IEEE 754 standard).

Comment: I would suggest that floating-point math doesn't really have positive and negative zeroes so much as it has positive and negative infinitesimals, but most implementations lack a true zero or unsigned infinitesimals and substitute a positive infinitesimal instead.  If x is a positive number which is small enough that x*x would underflow, then I would suggest that 1/(x*x) should yield "+INF" [since x*x is clearly positive] but 1/(x-x) should yield "NaN" [because x-x should be neither positive nor negative].

Comment: supercat,  Floating point implementation in computers has representation for zero.   " if every bit is zero (the sign bit being irrelevant), then the number is considered zero."  From here -> http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/floating_point/understanding_floating_point_representation.html

Comment: @supercat This answer is basically saying that it's useful to define division by zero in discrete mathematical systems that attempt to *approximate* the real numbers. In such systems, zero can be used as an approximation for values too small for the system to represent, and so it's useful to have a definition for what happens when you divide by it. Whether that's a *good* idea or there are better ideas is, of course, up for debate, but it is a real world system that's widely used. So +1.

Comment: @r12: In trying to have the sign of 1/(x*y) remain constant as the product becomes too small to represent, IEEE-754 severely damaged other aspects of the structure of floating-point numbers. For example, x==y should imply 1/x==1/y, but in IEEE-754 it doesn't.  x-y should be equivalent to -1*(y-x), but in IEEE-754, it doesn't, etc.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, in projective geometry or hyperbolic geometry for example, you can see applications or geometric entities that are $\frac{a}{0}$ or just $ \infty$ . Generally, non-euclidean spaces have such type of entities or applications.

Answer (score 6):

Theory of relativity.
$$m = \frac {m_0}{\sqrt{1 – (\frac vc)^2}}$$
This means that as your velocity (speed) increases, and gets closer and closer to the speed of light, your mass increases (therefore, mass is related to velocity). It also proves, that it is impossible to travel faster than the speed of light. If an object were to do that, its mass would reach infinity, and that is impossible, so travelling faster than the speed of light is impossible.

Comment: no, actually you reach infinity when $v = c$, and there are particles that do what (they have $m_0 = 0$). Going faster then $c$ would mean that the square root becomes complex. I don't know about physics but my guess is that in that case this equation can no longer be used. (and the existence of this equation per se does not imply that $v > c$ is impossible, only that this equation makes sense only when $v < c$)

Comment: Traveling faster than light is perfectly well-defined (if complex) in that formula.  All it really says is that your velocity can't pass *through* the speed of light.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is asking about forms of math that *do* allow for division by zero. The conclusions you mention *require* that division by zero be **undefined**. You reach these conclusions by taking a limit and showing that it approaches infinity (which is just a shorthand for "is unbounded" when discussing limits). If you define division by zero, then the mass becomes whatever value you defined $\frac{m_0}{0}$ to be (which may or may not be some kind of "legitimate" infinity). Bottom line: defining $\frac{1}{0}$ doesn't help here; it makes things harder.

Comment: @Mark If you allow $m$ to have complex values, then yes, it is well defined. This equation is only useful for particles with real positive mass, since other values don't let us draw any physical conclusions (as far as I know, anyway). So you can rule out $v > c$ on that basis.

Answer (score 4):

Though not actually correct, I've seen it used to "trick" people with a [***proof* that 1=0**](https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10001.1-8.shtml)

> Consider two non-zero numbers x and y such that
>
> $x = y$
>
> Then $x^2 = xy$
>
> Subtract the same thing from both sides:
>
> $x^2 - y^2 = xy - y^2$
>
> Dividing by $(x-y)$, obtain
>
> $x + y = y$
>
> Since $x = y$, we see that
>
> $2 y = y$
>
> Thus $2 = 1$, since we started with y nonzero.
>
> Subtracting 1 from both sides,
>
> $1 = 0$

<sub>Su, Francis E., et al. "One Equals Zero!." Math Fun Facts. http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts</sub>

Comment: You just divided numbers by (x - y) which is zero because x and y are different from zero and x = y, you can't divide a number by zero, it's against the laws of mathematics.

Comment: @GingerHead That's the point, and why it's a "trick" (that's explained in the link). Still, it *is* an application of dividing by zero

Comment: OK, I get your point, we used to do this at highschool

Answer (score 3):

In two dimensional space, if we want a vector corresponding to a given angle $t$, we can do:

$(x, y) = ( \cos(t), \sin(t) )$

But what about the reverse?  We have a vector, and want to know the angle.  A common solution is to use [arctan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#arctan):

$t = \arctan( \frac{y}{x} )$

Here $\frac{y}{x}$ represents the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) of the vector. So it has a meaningful value even when $x = 0$.

---

Trivia: Many program languages will fail to perform that calculation, because division by zero will produce an error.  They usual address this by offering an alternative function which takes two arguments: `atan2(y, x)`.

But a notable exception is Javascript, which has the concept of `+Infinity` and `-Infinity` as numbers, and can perform this calculation even when *x* = 0.

```
$ node
> Math.atan( 1 / 0 )
1.5707963267948966           (Pi/2)
> Math.atan( -1 / 0 )
-1.5707963267948966          (-Pi/2)
```

Another language which can perform this calculation is Haskell.

---

Inspired by [Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/232/qiaochu-yuan)'s comment.

Answer (score 2):

I gave an answer to a similar question some time ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/633298/400).

To put it briefly, if you are ever solving an equation in one variable by just addition, multiplication, subtraction, and division, and you end up with a contradiction, then you can conclude with certainty that the one time you divided both sides by an expression involving a variable, the expression you divided by was actually $0$ (because having multiple answers can only happen if you had a $\frac 00$).

Also, when computing limits, if you get a $\frac a0$ for $a\neq0$, you can directly conclude the limit does not exist (as a finite number).