# Is there a name for $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}}$?

Tags: functions

The function

$$\frac{1}{\;\;\dfrac{1}{x} + \dfrac1{y}\;\;}$$

shows up a lot, e.g., in parallel resistance or series conductance.  Does it have a name?  It is similar to [*harmonic mean*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) with the difference that the numerator is one rather than the number of terms.

Can it be called harmonic sum?  I think it stands to reason that since:

- you can replace $n$ series resistors with $n$ equal resistors having resistance equal to the mean of those resistors,
- you can replace $n$ parallel resistors with $n$ equal reistors having resistance equal to the harmonic mean of those resistance, and
- you can replace $n$ series resistor with 1 resistor having resistance equal to the sum of those resistors, then

— by analogy — you should be able to replace $n$ parallel resistors with 1 resistor having resistance equal to the “harmonic sum” of those resistors.

That is, *mean* is to *harmonic mean* as *sum* is to “*harmonic sum*”.

Comment: I remember the equation $\frac{1}{h}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$ occuring in optics (with other letters), but I do not know what "h" means mathematically.

Comment: @Peter: The numerator needs to be 2 if we want the harmonic mean of a number and itself to be that number again.

Comment: OK , I must have mixed something. The "h" in my equation should have a similar meaning

Comment: @Blue I know the definition of harmonic mean.  I mentioned it in the question!  And if there are three terms the numerator would have to be 3, etc.  The question is is there a name for this pattern when the numerator does not depend on the number of terms.

Comment: @Blue Ah, cool.  Feel free to edit the question :)

Comment: I don't think the operation has an established name. It is common enough, for instance when calculating the resistance of resistors in parallel, or the total time for two people to finish a set amount of work given the time they would each take it they were alone, that if it had a name, I think we would've heard about it.

Comment: The subsection of the Wikipedia article on harmonic mean concerning physics has a discussion comparing the roles of harmonic mean for parallel resistance and arithmetic mean for series resistance.  That discussion makes a point in a way that does generalize from two resistors to any fixed number.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for sharing that.  I had read it before posting, and I now edited the question to explain my logic.

Comment: "half of the harmonic mean"?

Comment: Maybe call it 'reduced harmonic mean' ? Sounds kinda nice and it is also connected to reduced masses.

Comment: It is also the answer to the question: If one worker can perform a certain task in x time-units and another can perform the same task in y time-units; then if the two workers are to perform the task in tandem, how many time-units will be required?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean#In_physics

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785715

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there were not already an established meaning for "harmonic sum", your choice of a name for the expression $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}}$ would be suitable.

Unfortunately harmonic sum is already widely used in connection with the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) and its partial sums.

Even so, if you wished to reuse this phrase or introduce a novel one for this type of expression, you are free to do so in mathematical exposition if you provide a definition and make clear that your choice is not to be confused with conventional terminology.  For example, if pressed I might be tempted to call these sorts of values *unweighted harmonic means*.  The phrase is not self-explanatory, but it is odd enough to motivate a careful Reader to check my definition and see that it differs from the usual harmonic mean.