# When am I allowed to remove a term by dividing 0 by the term

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It seems that you are allowed to remove terms from an equation if there is a 0 on the other side of the equals sign:
$$
3x = 0
$$
$$
\frac{3x}{3} = \frac{0}{3}
$$
$$
x = 0
$$
However, you can't just do whatever you want:
$$
3x = 0
$$
$$
\frac{3x}{x} = \frac{0}{x}
$$
$$
3 \ne 0
$$

---

$$
3x^2 + 2x - 4 = 0
$$
$$
\frac{3x^2 + 2x - 4}{3x^2 + 2x - 4} = \frac{0}{3x^2 + 2x - 4}
$$
$$
1 \ne 0
$$
What exactly is the rule here? Is it simply unsafe only when the denominator would contain a variable or be 0? When is dividing 0 by something to remove that something from the equation allowed/safe, if ever?

Comment: `When is dividing 0 by something to remove that something from the equation allowed/safe` When you can guarantee that the "something" is never $0$. For example, you can divide by $3$ because $3 \ne 0$, but you cannot divide by $x$ because you do *not* know that $x \ne 0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/633298/400 <- this answer may be relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't ever divide by something that *is* zero.  And if something *might* be zero, you must consider that it might not be to divide by the thing you are dividing.

Suppose you had $x^2 +x -6 = (x+2)(x-3) = 0$

But you are allowed to try.  If you do try and get a valid result you can state the result is valid but *only if* the thing you were dividing by was not $0$.

So I can say *if* $x-3 \ne 0$ then I can do the following

$\frac {(x+2)(x-3)}{x-3}=\frac {0}{x-3} $ (!!!***IF***!!! $x -3 \ne 0$)

$x+2 = 0$

$x=-2$.

So I can conclude $x = 2$ ***IF*** $x -3 \ne 0$.

But if  I do that I *MUST* immediately also consider the case that will happen if $x-3$ *DOES* equal $0$.

So I *must* conclude.

$x = -2$ if $x-3 \ne 0$ and if $x -3$ does equal $0$ then $x = 3$.

So either $x = -2$ or $x = 3$.

However if I try to divide and *don't* get a valid result, then we can conlcude we weren't allowed to do that.

Example:  Let $(x^2 + 2)(x-3) = 0$

And I try:  IF $x - 3 \ne 0$ then

$\frac {(x^2 + 2)(x-3)}{x-3} =\frac 0{x-3}$

$x^2 + 2 = 0$

so $x^2 = -2$.  .... but that's impossible.

Then I must conclude, hmmm, I guess $x - 3\ne 0$ was false, and instead $x -3 = 0$ so $x = 3$.

Note: that is exactly the result we would have gotten if we had divide by $x^2 + 2$ instead.

Ex:  Now we know $x^2 \ge 0$ so $x^2 + 2 \ge 2$ so $x^2 + 2 \ne 0$.  So we *can* do

$\frac {(x^2 +2)(x-3)}{x^2 + 2} = \frac 0{x^2 + 2}$

$x -3 = 0$

$x = 3$.

Now one nifty thing about $a*b = 0$.

If you have that, then you *know* without a doubt, that *one* of $a$ or $b$ (or possibly both) is equal to $0$.

Comment: there are lots of great answers, but I thought this one was the most thorough. the $x^2+2$ case was especially interesting and helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You're dividing by zero in both cases which leads to fallacious results.

In the first equation, solving for $x$ leads to $x=0$. Thus, you cannot divide by it. You can divide by $3$ because $3 \ne 0$.

The same applies for the latter. You are *explicitly guaranteeing it is zero because you are equating it to $0$*.

Answer (score 1):

When you work in a field as $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, dividing by $0$ is not allowed. On the other hand, you can divide by any non-zero element.

Consider $3x = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}$. If you multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{3}$ you get $x = 0$. So you cannot divide by $x$.

In the last case, you have $3x^2+2x-4=0$. This forces $x$ to be one of the two real roots of the polynomial in question. So you cannot divide both sides by the polynomial, because you would divide by $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Rule #1

You can never divide a number or an expression by $0$

Rule #2

If you are dividing a number or an expression by an expression make sure that the  denominator is not zero. For example $$3x=0 \iff \frac {3}{x}={0}{x}$$ only if $x\ne 0$

Rule #3

Do not multiply both sides of an equation  by another expression without making sure that the expression is not $0$

for example $$ \frac {3x+2}{x-5}=  \frac {x+4}{x-5} \iff {3x+2}={x+4}$$ only if $x\ne 5 $